# Awkward criteria when generating random sequence

Tags: php, random, numbers, sequence

What I need to do to generate a sequence of non-repeating integers within a given range that meets the specific criteria that I have?

Here are the criteria:

1. Use only the numbers between 1 and MAX (let's say 9).
2. Numbers cannot repeat within the sequence except:

   2a. Two of the first 5 numbers from the sequence must be repeated.

   2b. These two numbers must be repeated at random points within the last 5 places in the final sequence (the last 5 includes the repeats).

For example:
`SET: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9`

Random Sequence (with repeats):
     `2,4,6,9,3,1,5,2,8,7,3`
     `r, , , ,r, , ,x, , ,x`

Here I have indicated the numbers that were randomly selected to be repeated (out of the first 5 in the random sequence) with an `r` and the insertion points where they were randomly placed (into the last 5 of the final sequence) with an `x`.

Any help in figuring this out is much appreciated. Actual use will be a bit more complicated than this, but I know what I will need to do once I can get this far.

**Edit**

To clarify a little more, I have 1-20, and I need a 22 digit random sequence. Every number must be used, two will be used twice as discussed in my original post. I chose 10 above to simplify a little. I should be able to adapt the logic you've all given.

Comment: Can't help myself: http://xkcd.com/221/

Comment: I've merged your unregistered accounts. You should now be able to leave comments under answers, edit your question and eventually accept an answer that helped you. Please, don't add additional answers as an update to your question, Stack Overflow is not a forum.

Answer (score 0):

I assume when you say "non-repeating" you mean "distinct" (unique) as opposed to "eventually becomes periodic" (as in "the digits of pi do not repeat")

1. Generate *n* distinct integers in your range.
2. Pick two from the first 5. Call these *a* and *b*.
3. Remove the last 3 from the list.
4. Insert *a* at position 0, 1, 2, or 3 in the sublist.
5. Insert *b* at position 0, 1, 2, 3, or 4 in the sublist.
6. Add the sublist back to the end of the list.

Removal of the sublist is not necessary but makes it easier to conceptualize.

Not obvious what to do if n+2 is less than 10. In particular, this algorithm may crash for n < 5 and return the wrong result for n=7.

Answer (score 0):

To generate distinct numbers within a range you can use something like this:

```
$arr_num = array();

while(count($arr_num)<=7)
{
  $num = rand(1, 9);
  if (!in_array($num, $arr_num))
  {
    $arr_num[] = $num;
  }
}
```

$arr_num now has 8 distinct elements. Pick five elements of the array:

```
for ($i=0; $i<=4; $i+=1)
{
  $new_arr[$i] = $arr_num[$i];
}
```

Now pick two numbers from $new_arr numbers:

```
$r1 = array_rand($new_arr);
$r2 = array_rand($new_arr);
```

Now you can insert these numbers into the original array at two of the last random positions. Hope it helped!

Comment: The elements in that `$arr_num` array will be distinct, but it's somewhat unlikely that they'll be 7.

Comment: That's right! I will modify it so that it has (n) distinct elements!

Comment: Now the loop has a small chance that it'll never finish, at the very least it can be very expensive. Is O(rand) a valid Big O notation for this? ;-3

Comment: I tested it for upto 20 numbers and it works fine. However for a large range it might not end at all. And I didn't get your point regarding "Big O notation"?!?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you have 1 to N random numbers that must be used in a 10-set permutation with some specific criteria about repeats.  In php, I suggest this (not counting php-internals) O(n) solution:

```
//Generate a full list of keys
$source = range(1, MAX);
//NOTE: if MAX < 10, you must pad the array

//Get a random group of 10 of the keys
$input = array_rand(array_flip($source), 10);

//Shuffle (can be done later as well; this is the randomization).
//array_rand() does not change order.
shuffle($input);

//Select the first of 5 that must be repeated in the last 5
$one = rand(0, 4);
$onev = $input[$one];

//Remove this array key to prevent collisions with the second of 5
$input = array_diff($input, array($onev));

//Select a random index in the last 5 to be replaced with $one
$rep = rand(5, 9);
$repv = $input[$rep];

//Remove this array key to prevent collisions with the other to-be-replaced
$input = array_diff($input, array($repv));

//Acquire the new keys list of input now that two elements have been removed
$keys = array_slice(array_keys($input), 0, 3);
//Select the second-of-5 to replace in the last 5.  No worry of collision now.
$two = array_rand($keys, 1);
$two = $keys[$two];

//Select the second from the last-of-5 to be replaced by $two
//No worry of collision because the other index is removed.
$keys = array_slice(array_keys($input), 4, 8);
$rept = array_rand($keys, 1);
$rept = $keys[$rept];

//Replace one of the last-of-five with one of the first-of-five
$input[$rept] = $input[$two];

//Restore removed keys as well as perform replacement of other last-of-five
$input[$one] = $onev;
$input[$rep] = $onev;

//re-randomize based on shuffle
ksort($input);
```

No loops, no conditionals.

Answer (score 0):

```
$max = 15;

$array = array(1, $max);
for($x = 1; $x <= $max; $x++)
{ $array[$x] = rand(1, $max); }

$firstDup = $array[rand(1,5)];
$secondDup = $firstDup;
do { $firstDup = $array[rand(1,5)];
} while($firstDup == $secondDup);

do { $array[rand($max-5,$max)] = $firstDup;
} while(!in_array($firstDup,array_slice($array,$max-5,5)));

do { $array[rand($max-5,$max)] = $secondDup;
} while(!in_array($secondDup,array_slice($array,$max-5,5)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this gets you on your way:

```
$max = 20;    // max value
$repeats = 2; // numbers to be repeated

$nums = range(1, $max);
shuffle($nums);

$halfPoint = ceil($max / 2);
$firstHalf = array_slice($nums, 0, $halfPoint);

$repeaters = array_intersect_key($firstHalf, array_flip(array_rand($firstHalf, $repeats)));
$secondHalf = array_merge(array_slice($nums, $halfPoint), $repeaters);
shuffle($secondHalf);

$result = array_merge($firstHalf, $secondHalf);

var_dump(join(',', $result));
```

Answer (score 0):

A word of warning on this solution. I wouldn't use it for a large set of numbers. If I were doing this same solution for a much larger set, I would use array_splice to drop chosen members from the array. As you get a much larger space, finding an unused number in your range becomes quite expensive, and demands a better solution than the brute force method below.

This will build half of your target set. You will call it twice, once for each half.

```
function build_half($min, $max, $num_elements, $arr = array() ){

  while( count($arr) <= $num_elements)
   {
      $candidate = rand($min, $max);
      if( !in_array($candidate, $arr))
        {
          array_push($arr, $candidate);
        }
    }
   return $arr;
}
```

This will grab $this_many elements from the array.

```
function random_grab($arr, $this_many){      // don't try this on the subway
  $nums_to_repeat = array();

  // catch some edge cases...
  if( $this_many > count($arr) )
    {
      return FALSE;
    }
  else if( $this_many == count($arr) )
    {
      return shuffle($arr);
    }

  while( count($nums_to_repeat) <= $this_many) 
    {
      $rand_key = rand(0, count($arr) - 1);

      if( ! in_array($arr[$rand_key], $nums_to_repeat))
        {
          array_push($nums_to_repeat, $arr[$rand_key]);
        }
    }
 return $nums_to_repeat;
}
```

This is a fairly specialized case, but could be made more general by allowing the offset floor and ceiling to be passed in as parameters. For your problem they would be 5 and 9, so we just derive them directly.

```
function random_insert_2nd_half($target, $source){
  $offsets_consumed = array();
  $num_elements = count($target);

  while( count($source) > 0 )
    {
      $offset = rand( ($num_elements/2), $num_elements - 1);

      if( ! in_array( $offset, $offsets_consumed)
        {
          $arr[$offset] = array_pop($nums_to_repeat);
        }
    }
}
```

Ok so after having done all that, let's put it to work.

```
// Generate the first half of the array
$my_array = $repeated_nums = array();
$my_array = build_half(1, 10, 5);

// then grab the 2 random numbers from that first half.
$repeated_nums = random_grab($my_array, 2);

// So now we have our random numbers and can build the 2nd half of the array.
// we'll just repeat the call to the first function.
$my_array = build_half(1, 10, 5, $my_array);

// Then swap out two of the values in the second half.
$my_array = random_insert_2nd_half($my_array, $repeated_nums);

// at this point $my_array should match what you are looking for.
```